# Effective resistance across 2 adjacent vertices of a dodecahedron with each edge $r$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance

What will be the effective resistance across 2 adjacent vertices of a regular dodecahedron (12 faces) with each *edge* having resistance $r$?

[Here](http://www.ioc.ee/~kalda/ipho/e-circuits.pdf) is the source for the problem, it's problem 20. on the sheet.

In the link, a typical problem is solved using symmetry (infinite square lattice, resistance between adjacent vertices) and then it is stated

> It appears that such a symmetrization technique can be also applied to ﬁnite lattices.

I am looking for some ideas as to how to apply this technique to a dodecahedron. More generally, I am looking for examples where such *symmetrization techniques* can be used for finite lattices.

[image: Dodecahedron]

Comment: You can certainly cut it in half and identify nodes at equal potential. The edges between those nodes can then be cut to simplify further. Alternatively you can apply a star-mesh transform to it, which should lead to the geometric dual and that may have fewer nodes (20 down to 12... maybe I am missing something)?

Comment: @CuriousOne I get your idea, but won't that be too hectic for a dodecahedron? Afterall 12 nodes isn't too less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the problem symmetric, consider this: What happens, when you take the dodecahedron and drive current $I$ into it from vertex $A$ and drive $I/20$ out from all every vertex (including $A$)? By Kirchhoff's laws and symmetry, there is a current

$I_{A-out} = \frac{(I-I/20)}{3} = \frac{19}{60}I$

going from $A$ to neighbouring vertexes.

Now suppose $B$ is a neighbour of $A$ and we do the same for $B$, but with current $-I$ (so current is flowing into $B$ from nearby vertexes). Again we find there is a current

$I_{B-in} = \frac{19}{60} I$

flowing into $B$. Now we superpose these solutions - we get a solution, where there is current $I$ going into $A$ and it all comes out from $B$. Also notice that $\pm I/20$ leaving from each vertex has also vanished. However the edge connecting $A$ and $B$ has current

$I' = I_{A-out} + I_{B-in} = \frac{19}{30} I$

So the voltage between $A$ and $B$ is $U = I'r$, thus

$U/I' = \frac{19}{30} r$

(which is the correct answer).

---

I decided to solve this problem instead of simply giving ideas, because the solution used some ideas from previous problems on the sheet, so it is probably more useful for other users this way.

Comment: I love this approach. How would one generalize to any two nodes (for example, if the two nodes were not adjacent?)

Comment: @Floris: With dodecahedron, it is possible to do it with any two nodes, because it is possible to find the current (when all current comes from $A$) in any edge using symmetry only. Later you can find the voltage between $A$ and $B$ by adding several voltages on resistors. However notice that in an infinite lattice, this isn't so simple (or even possible) because current doesn't distribute evenly between nodes further away.

Comment: This is very elegant, but where in all of this are we using the fact that it's a dodecahedron and not some other circuit topology with the same number of vertices? Where is the information contained that all branches have equal resistance?

Comment: *"Now we superpose these solutions"* -- what exactly does "superpose" mean?  (There should be some extra conditions -- see @CuriousOne's comment, or the question why you couldn't assign different currents to different vertices such that they cancel everywhere.)

Comment: @CuriousOne: Well, it essentially proves that every circuit with 20 nodes, such that 3 edges are connected to each node and each node is symmetrical to any other node (because if that was not the case, my assumption of even distribution of currents might become false) has an effective resistance of $\frac{19}{30} r$. I suspect that this might be the only circuit that would match these constraints. However, if there are others, it proves that all these circuits have the same resistance.

Comment: @CuriousOne And I can use symmetry because all resistances are equal.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The comment to CuriousOne should answer most of your question. Giving different currents to different nodes is not a good idea, because I ensure that initially all current distributes evenly from $A$ by simply using the fact the situation is symmetric with respect to all 3 directions the current can go. For the proof to work, these currents have to be symmetric also with respect to $B$. By far the simplest (and possibly the only) way is to take an equal $I/20$ from every node.

Comment: @kristjan It's not that I dislike the argument, I just don't see how one would be able to put this into equations (which makes me suspicious). If you assume that some current is leaving from each vertex, you have to apply a potential there.  What if the potential for A and B are different? What does superposing mean in that case?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Suppose the initial state (with $19I/20$ going into $A$) can be achieved with potentials $\phi$, $\phi + \phi_2$, $\phi + \phi_3$, $\phi + \phi_4$, ... applied to nodes 1, 2, ... Here $\phi$ can be varied freely. The same thing for the second state ($19I/20$ leaving the circuit from $B$) is achieved with some other potentials $\phi'$, $\phi' + \phi_2'$, ... Superposing those means adding the corresponding potentials. Then $U = U_{AB} = \phi + \phi_B + \phi' + \phi_B' -  \phi - \phi_A - \phi' - \phi_A' = \phi_B + \phi_B' - \phi_A - \phi_A'$ (independent of $\phi$ and $\phi'$).

Comment: @kristjan: I am still not convinced. As you can see from your added comments, your proof leaves out too much. Maybe you can "see" this, I can't. Admittedly, that may be due to my limitations.